Is Insertion into a vector while also accessing a vector undefined behavior?
Just stumbled upon a post that talked about reference and iterator invalidation on insertion into a vector.
But will accessing a vector by index also result in undefined behavior?
Is the below code correct?
std::vector<int> data {0, 1, 2};
// EDIT: Fixing error '... i < data.size(); ...'
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  auto end = data.size();
  // Using 'for (const auto &v : data) {' below seems to be causing segfault
  // on some platforms and not on others, but clearly is wrong use of a reference
  for (int j = 0; j < end; ++j) {
    data.emplace_back(data.at(j) + end);
  }
}

This question stems from:
Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers

The use of indices in a loop while modifying the vector is fine, and it's not directly the issue here. The problem is that you're growing the vector indefinitely. The looping condition tests i < data.size(), which in essence will always be true because the vector size grows faster than i does.
The undefined behavior arises because you're using signed integers as indices. Once i reaches std::numeric_limits<int>::max() then you have a problem. At this point, executing ++i has undefined behavior according to the C++ standard.
If you instead use unsigned integers (e.g. std::size_t, or more correctly std::vector<int>::size_type), you no longer have undefined behavior but you instead have an infinite loop. The loop will continue until the vector fails to reallocate and throws std::bad_alloc. If you are not handling this exception then your program will crash.
Technically, the loop isn't infinite. You're limited by the available RAM (as above), but also the vector's maximum size. If you happen to have endless memory available, the call to emplace_back will eventually throw std::length_error when the vector cannot grow any further.

I apologize for the mistake in the example, I fixed it. But more so the question was focused around the validity of using indices while modifying the vector.
So, even if the vector is resized, we can keep using indices and it will remain valid?

Yes, you can. In simplistic terms, the reason iterators are invalidated is because it's usually most efficient to implement them using pointers. So if the data is moved elsewhere in memory (due to a resize) then accessing through that pointer is a disaster. To avoid that, the standard defines a rule saying you must not use the iterator after certain operations. Conversely, accessing via an index always calculates the correct address as an offset from the actual storage. If you weren't allowed to use an index after resizing, then std::vector would be basically worthless.

I want to point out that you can actually use iterators while pushing data onto a vector, provided you know for sure that the vector won't be resized as a result. The rules only say that the iterator is invalidated if pushing results in a resize. Good practice is to always call reserve if you know what the final size of your vector will be. Not doing so is lazy and can also create unnecessary pressure on the memory allocator. In more extreme cases it can be a driver of memory fragmentation which can have a serious impact on performance.
